# Turn a string into a vector of strings

Tags: c++

I've been trying to use the `std::string::find()` method to turn a `std::string` into a `std::vector` of lines, but I keep encountering an infinite loop.

```
//string is called print
int start=0;

while(start<print.size())
{
    int end=print.find("\n",start);
    to_print.push_back(print.substr(start,end));
    start=end+1;
}

for(int j=0;j<to_print.size();j++)
{
    cout<<to_print[j];
}
```

Comment: Please modify your example so that it (1) can be tried directly by readers, and (2) reproduces the problem.

Comment: Wth is with the title??

Comment: @LogicStuff I think it a word

Answer (score 2):

You should change the while loop as follows:

```
while (start < print.size())
{
    int end = print.find("\n", start);
    if (end != string::npos)
    {
        to_print.push_back(print.substr(start, end));
        start = end + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        to_print.push_back(print.substr(start));
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You example is not complete, as it should be, but in essence, when `find` doesn't find something it returns `npos`, which converted to signed `int` is -1. And then `start=end+1` adds 0 to `start`. Hence `start` doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

You are not accounting for the case that when the loop reaches the last line in the string, `find()` returns `std::string::npos` because `"\n"` is no longer found.

That being said, you can use a `std::istringstream` with `std::getline()` to parse the lines without searching for them manually, eg:

```
#include <sstream>

std::istringstream iss(print);
std::string line;
while (std::getline(iss, line))
{
    to_print.push_back(line);
}
```

Alternatively, you can avoid the manual loop altogether by using `std::copy()` with `std::istream_iterator` and `std::back_inserter`, eg:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

class line : public std::string {}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &in, line &l)
{
    return std::getline(in, l);
}

std::istringstream iss(print);
std::copy(
    std::istream_iterator<line>(iss),
    std::istream_iterator<line>(),
    std::back_inserter(to_print)
);
```